# EditText goes on multiple lines when reaches the end Android

Tags: android

I have an EditText that is a Username input field, This is the xml:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColorHint="@color/placeholdColor"
        android:background="@drawable/bordertext" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

The problem is that if I write more than a line of text the EditText goes on multiple lines.. How can I set it to stay only in one line and if it reaches the end it just continues on the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following

```
android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <EditText
    ...
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    ...
   </EditText>
```